# What is wrong with rsync?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've problem with entrypoint in my docker container..
My Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
[....]
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html \
&& mkdir -p /var/www/html2 \
&& mkdir -p /var/www/storage

COPY . /var/www/html2
[....]
WORKDIR /var/www

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/rsync", "-r", "-A", "/var/www/html2/\*", "/var/www/html/" ]
```

I need sync code from html2 to html directory.
All seems to work, but rsync report error:

> php-fpm    | rsync: [sender] link_stat "/var/www/html2/*" failed: No such file or directory (2)

When I run docker in command line all seems to work ok:

```
docker-compose run --entrypoint "ls -lah /var/www/"  php-fpm

Creating deploy_php-fpm_run ... done
total 20K
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4.0K Aug  5 20:40 .
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4.0K Jul 28 10:58 ..
drwxr-xr-x 17 root root 4.0K Aug  5 21:08 html
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4.0K Aug  5 21:03 html2
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4.0K Aug  5 16:59 storage
```

What I doing wrong ? No any error at build time. html2 directory contains my code.

Comment: Why not just  `/usr/bin/rsync -r -A /var/www/html2/ /var/www/html/` synchronize directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the [exec form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example) of `ENTRYPOINT`, nothing expands the `*` in the argument list.  You are literally passing the string `/var/www/html2/*` to `rsync`, which in turn is looking for a single file named `*`.

You can get around this by using the [shell form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example) instead, which essentially amounts to removing the JSON-array syntax.  This will cause Docker to run a shell to interpret the command, and that shell will expand the `*`.

```bash
ENTRYPOINT /usr/bin/rsync -r -A /var/www/html2/* /var/www/html/
```

Remember that a container only runs a single command and then exits.  The command as you've shown it means that the container will copy content from one place to another in the container temporary filesystem, and then immediately exit.  It would make more sense to `COPY` the content to the right directory to start with, and then use the `CMD` to run the actual application.  (I tend to prefer `CMD` to `ENTRYPOINT` for being easier to override in `docker run` and for fitting better with the entrypoint wrapper script pattern.)

```bash
FROM php:8.1-fpm
...
COPY . /var/www/html # use the right directory in the image
...
# don't set ENTRYPOINT or CMD at all
# base image specifies `CMD ["php-fpm"]`
```